# how to parse multiple xml data?

Tags: objective-c, xml, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I was able to get the top 10 free apps from iTunes, but I have one problem when I try to get the image I get 3 images.

[**source link**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=10/xml)

This is the code that pull the string:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"im:name"]){   
        [title appendString:string];


    }else if ([element isEqualToString:@"im:image"]) {   
        [image appendString:string];
    }

}
```

Because there are 3 image sizes it pulls all of them:

```
<im:image height="53">  
<im:image height="75">  
<im:image height="100">
```

if I try to put the image size I want, it doesn't work.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this callback

`-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict;`

and grab attributeDict to get the attribute whenever the element name is `im:image`.

You will have to make an array or something similar if you want to store all of the heights, but that callback is where you would do it. So something like this:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
     attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

      if([elementName isEqualToString:@"im:image"])
           [heightArray addObject:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"height"]];
}
```